# How do I get rid of zeroes in a pascal's triangle matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have managed to code a function for plotting a pascal's triangle in the form of a matrix, but want to make it look like a triangle.

When I ask for a pascal's triangle with four rows, it gives

1 0 0 0

1 1 0 0

1 2 1 0

1 3 3 1

Is there a possible way to make this

1

1 1

1 2 1

1 3 3 1

```
function x = testfunc(n)

  x = eye(n);
  x(:, 1) = 1;


  for j=3:n
    for i = 2 : n - 1
      x(j, i) = x(j - 1, i - 1) + x(j - 1, i);
    end
  end

end
```

This is my code so far

Answer (score 0):

If you are just interested in the visuals then you can turn it into an cell-array and then use `cellfun` to loop over all cells and then only display the values that are not 0.

```
a= mat2cell(x,ones(n,1),n); %turn into cell array
cellfun(@(a)disp(a(a~=0)),a) %loop over cells and print only nonzero elements
```

If you are interested in saving memory, you can either use cell arrays from the beginning or turn it into a sparse matrix, e.g.

```
x = sparse(eye(n));
```

Then only non-zero elements will be represented